# When copying files from Android to Linux via mtp datetime unadvertently changes by diffrence of mobile's and Linux time zones

Tags: linux, linux-mint, usb, android, mtp

Edit 2:

Issue:

Modification time of file as shown by `stat` in Linux for files copied from Android via usb is effected by changing of time zone setting on Android after file was created.

Reperformance:

1. Boot Ubuntu 20.4 (or Linux Mint 21) from live USB.
2. On Android (I had version 11, also observed the effect for 9) set datetime and time zone to manual, put in offline mode.
3. Connect Android to Linux via usb.
4. Pick a file on Android, copy via file manager to location_1 on Linux.
5. Run `stat` on copied file (one in location_1).
6. Disconnect usb (important).
7. Change time zone on Android by several hours.
8. Reconnect usb.
9. Copy same file from Android to location_2.
10. Run `stat` on copied file (one in location_2).
11. Observe difference on line with `Modify` of several hours.

**OP:**

There was a question asked in 2013 [How do I transfer files between Android and Linux over USB?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87762/how-do-i-transfer-files-between-android-and-linux-over-usb). Updated answer dated 2018 states that mtp works:

> it seems most Linux distros are now working with MTP fairly well. I
> know in my experience, Mint (Ubuntu based) works out of the box

Indeed I connect device via USB, click in Nemo (GUI) on an icon, storage mounts and I can transfer files in GUI.

However I just noted time zone matters. When I change time zone on a phone files modification times change. And copied to Linux, they remain with those times and Linux time zone (per `stat`), regardless of device's time zone, so files' "original" (phone's) time zone correction info is just lost. IMO not a desired effect, albeit rarely manifested as usually devices in close physical proximity have same time zone set.

Does that effect is due to how `mtp` works or it might depend on something else? Any advice how to copy with correct times w/out making sure both devices have same time zone set at the time of copying files? TIA

P.S. I think I want to report a bug, but not sure where: Mint, Ubuntu, Debian, kernel, else?

**Added example:**

A file on Android with time zone +1, Linux time zone +1

Android modification time as seen in both Android file manager and mtp mount in Linux Mint 21 based system in Nemo, say: 9:45:00.

After copy to ext4 fs `stat` shows for `Modify:`
`9:45:00.000000000 +0100`
Change time zone on Android to +3 (maybe unmount/replug usb/remount just in case), copy same file to other location on ext4, `stat` shows
`11:45:00.000000000 +0100`
Change time zone on Linux to +3. For second copy `stat` shows:
`13:45:00.000000000 +0300`

*Note: when time zones are selected via GUI by city (I don't know other way in my Linux BTW) due to possibility of date savings results might differ even more or less by one hour.*

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add specific examples, including the full date information from both devices. It is hard to see what you mean without examples.

Comment: The metadata stored at the filesystem level has no concept of timezones and I don't see any indication that `stat` returns timezone information. You might compare `ls -l .bash_profile` with `TZ=gmt ls -l .bash_profile`. Check the same with `stat` instead of `ls -l`. Essentially, a file does not have a "original time zone".

Comment: @tendon, I've edited the title and added an example. Due to me doing such time experiments on another PC it's not copy-paste but I hope now effect is clear.

Comment: @doneal24, on my Linux Mint 21 based system `stat` outputs time along with time zone, see added example. Now for some zone I even see time corrections differ for access and modify times (I guess due to one being during daytime savings other not).

Comment: @doneal24, P.S. yes, AFAIK on ext fs datetime is stored as seconds since epoch.

Comment: Please show us the time of the original, the exact xommand used to copy the file and then the time on the copy. Files do not have a "time zone", so you cannot change a file's time zone. You are changing the system time zone which affects how the time is displayed, but that has nothing to do with the file itself. As far as I can tell, what you describe is the normal behavior, assuming you are using a command that tries to preserve the modification date when copying, and I don't understand what you were expecting to see.

Comment: @tendon, I'm using Nemo to copy. I don't think it is normal that final date of file copied differs based on time zone set on device from where it is copied at time of copying - that is not preserving actual time, but changing it. I've added times, even those many zeros. How do you want me to find out time of the original on Android so that you believe me. I have many files copied with same effect.

Comment: @terdon, I've edited the question added Edit 2 at the beginning with clear (IMO) reperformance guide.

Answer (score 1):

Original timestamp on Android: `9:45:00.000000000 +0100` = 8:45:00 UTC.

After changing the timezone of Android to +0300 and transferring the file to Linux:

`11:45:00.000000000 +0100` = 10:45:00 UTC

[The MTP protocol specification](https://www.usb.org/document-library/media-transfer-protocol-v11-spec-and-mtp-v11-adopters-agreement) (page 22 of MTPforUSB-IFv1.1.pdf within the ZIP file) indicates the protocol handles timestamps as ISO 8601-compliant DateTime strings; however the indication of time zone is unfortunately **optional**.

The fact that the timestamp changed in transfer indicates the Android MTP implementation did not use the actual filesystem timestamp (which presumably is in UTC-equivalent form) but the localized timestamp presented in the Android UI.

I see three possible mechanisms for this error to happen:

- Android could be **erroneously converting the localized timestamp back to UTC** for transfer using the *current* Android timezone, instead of transferring the raw filesystem timestamp which is already in UTC. In this case, Android MTP implementation will include the information that the timestamp is in UTC and Linux implementation is using it as such.
- Android transferring the timestamp using the local time in Android's *current* timezone, but **not specifying the timezone** in the MTP DateTime string, causing Linux to assume the timestamp is in its own local timezone.
- Android transferring the timestamp using the local time in Android's current timezone and specifying the timezone in the DateTime string, but the Linux MTP implementation **not using the timezone information**, assuming its own local timezone.

Dumping the USB traffic with e.g. Wireshark + Linux `usbmon` kernel module should allow a conclusive identification of the cause of error.

Second copy after changing the timezone on Linux too:

`13:45:00.000000000 +0300` = 10:45:00 UTC = 11:45:00 +0100

The actual Linux-side timestamp (and so the error) is exactly the same as in the first copy, as both 13:45:00 +0300 and 11:45:00 +0100 refer to the same instant in time, i.e. 10:45:00 UTC. The same timestamp is just presented using a different local timezone.

If you look at the timestamp of the first transferred file on Linux, its modification time should also now say 13:45:00 +0300, as all timestamps formatted for local time will now be displayed using the +0300 timezone.

Comment: Thanks, second copy was added for completeness during back and forth in comments, it is as I expect to work. I have limited wireshark experience and do not understand how to apply "Linux usbmon kernel module". Could you please elaborate on how test could be made? In the meantime I'm going to try to understand myself.

Comment: I changed time zones both on Android and Linux and modify timestanp of copied files became different by total delta - changes in both timezones effected the result. Per my understanding of your answer it rules out 1st option.

Comment: If you first convert both the original's and the copy's timestamps to UTC and then compare them, was the difference in UTC 1x or 2x the magnitude of the timezone change?

Comment: Maybe I wrote imprecisely. "original's and the copy...1x or 2x the magnitude of the timezone change?" In comment above I've talked about two copies. I've made one, then changed time zones on both Android and Linux and recopied. Say were +7 / +1, became +6 / +2. Difference between 1st and 2nd copy (+7 - 1) - (+6 -2)= 2 hours.